# RAILS: undefined method `map' caused by missing I18n translation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I changed the format for a `datetime` field in a RAILS 4 `new.html.erb` from `:string` to `datetime` and it caused error as below:

```
undefined method `map' for "translation missing: zh-CN.date.order":String
```

The view code causing the error above is:

```
<%= f.input :start_time, :label => t("Start Time"), required: true, :as => :datetime, :ampm => true, :minute_step => 10, :start_year => Date.today.year - 1, :end_year => Date.today.year + 1, :format => 'YYYY/MM/DD/HH/MM', :use_month_numbers => true, :include_blank => true %>
```

The `RAILS` source code blows up is in `actionview/helpers/date_helper.rb`:

```
def translated_date_order
  date_order = I18n.translate(:'date.order', :locale => @options[:locale], :default => [])
  date_order = date_order.map { |element| element.to_sym }  #<<<<<<===blows up

  forbidden_elements = date_order - [:year, :month, :day]
  if forbidden_elements.any?
    raise StandardError,
      "#{@options[:locale]}.date.order only accepts :year, :month and :day"
  end

  date_order
end
```

I do have a file `zh-CN.yml` under `/config/locale/` and it is providing translations for others except this one.

UPDATE portion of `zh-CN.yml`:

```
zh-CN:

  #maint_recordx
  Mfg Batches  : '订单批次一览'
  New Batch  : '新批次'
  Update Batch : '更新批次'
  Edit Batch : '更新批次'
...........
```

Comment: And can you show a structure of .yml? Probably there's a small typo

Comment: You have a typo in your helper method: `:'date.order'`. Remove the `:`, it should just be a string. If that fixes it, I suggest you delete this question as it will no longer be applicable here.

Comment: `mmichael`, the helper method  is directly copied from Rails source code under /actionview/. Also removing it did not help.

Comment: `Igor Pavlov`, just added top part of the `zh-CN.yml`. The file is too big for posting. I checked the file again and did not find a typo. I also removed what I added today and it still did not help.

Comment: I have the same issue when using I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord and a translation is missing. There is not even a YML involved as ActiveRecord Backend for I18n will read from db records. Rails version is 5.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After being bitten by this same error, I found that Rails sets the following key:

```
:'date.order'
```

to the value:

```
["year", "month", "day"]
```

for the default `:en` locale

You can confirm this by running the following snippet in rails console for a default rails install:

```
date_order = I18n.translate(:'date.order', :locale => :en, :default => [])
```

Notice I just switched `@options[:locale]` for the default `:en` value

The rails helper you reference, expects an array for the date_order value, and will blow up if it doesn't get one.

In my case, I improperly configured the I18n::Backend::ActiveRecord gem and therefore it interfered with the value being returned by I18n. You probably have a similar issue preventing the correct value for the `:'date.order'` key being returned.

EDIT:

In order to fix this, you should probably just need to install the gem '`rails-i18n'`. It will handle returning the correct date formats for supported locales. In my case I had a custom configuration in my es.yml locale file that returned an incorrect date format.

Comment: @opotions[:locale]='zh-CN' which causes the error. But how to fix it? I have the config as: I18n.default_locale = 'zh-CN' if Rails.env.production? || Rails.env.development?  in local.rb under `/initializers/`

Answer (score 2):

Bingo !!! You just have to add the missing key translation to your local translations.
I solved it by adding

```
en:
  date:
    order: ["day", "month", "year"]
```

to

```
config/locales/en.yml
```